# Catchall Htacess Redirect Excluding Certain String

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to setup a catch all redirect that excludes a certain strings.

For catchall I am using the regex:

```
^(.*)$
```

How ever I would like to exclude urls such as domain.com/wp-admin/* and /wp-login.php

I came up with this regex, but it doesnt work:

```
^(?!(?:wp-admin/.*|wp-login.php.*))(.*)$
```

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you do not escape `/` after `wp-admin` (or the `.` between `login` and `php`), and the any character sequence `.*` for the lookahead can be at the beginning. Regarding this:

```
^(?!.*wp-admin\/.*|.*wp-login\.php)(.*)$
```

should be OK: https://regex101.com/r/j9IWcn/1

With:

- `(?!.*wp-admin\/.*|.*wp-login\.php)`: negative lookahead saying not

  - zero or unlimited character followed by "wp-admin/*" (with * here as a wildcard) or
  - zero or unlimited character followed by "wp-login.php"
- `(.*)`: anything just to validate the rest of the input